# Empty $_POST in PHP after ajax call with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function that collects data from some input fields and checkboxes.
I want to send that data to a PHP file and then return some information from a database.
But I have a problem getting the POST data in PHP so here I will only focus on that problem and won't deal with any database.

The data collected in the HTML form is returned in a Javascript object, I convert it to Json using `JSON.stringify(data)` and I get :

`{"motscle":[""],"categories":[1,2,3],"prix":[{"min":0,"max":50},{"min":50,"max":100},{"min":100,"max":200},{"min":200,"max":500},{"min":500,"max":1000},{"min":1000,"max":2000}],"dimensions":{"longueur":"","largeur":"","hauteur":""}}`

You can test it on http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to see the expanded form and to see it's a valid JSON. So, the problem is not here I thnk.

Then I have an ajax call like that for testing purpose (`var theJSON` contains the above JSON string) :

```
 $.ajax({                                      
          url: 'post.php',                           
          data: theJSON ,   
          dataType: 'json', 
          error: function(){
               console.log("Error in ajax request");
          },
          success: function(data)          
          {
               console.log("Success of ajax request");
               console.log(data);
          }
     });
```

My testing PHP file `post.php` is like that :

```
<?php
     header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
     echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

The ajax call is OK as I get that in the js console :

```
Success of ajax request
[]
```

However as you can see I have also a empty array `[]`. I was expecting to get the $_POST content that PHP should have sent me.

I don't know where I'm wrong. Why don't I get the data in `$_POST` ?

Comment: Open your browser's dev tools and watch the request / response in the console. You should see the data sent and the data returned. That's your starting point for troubleshooting.

Comment: Echo `$_GET` and see if that isn't empty. If GET is being populated, add the attribute `type: "POST"` into your ajax call.

Comment: @Rickkwa That was the problem, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default type of an ajax request is GET, either change the ajax

```
$.ajax({                                      
      url: 'post.php',                        
      type : 'POST',
      data: theJSON ,   
      dataType: 'json', 
      error: function(){
           console.log("Error in ajax request");
      },
      success: function(data)          
      {
           console.log("Success of ajax request");
           console.log(data);
      }
 });
```

or check GET

```
echo json_encode($_GET);
```

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem. I also had another problem. In fact I have to send `theJSON` as an object and not as a String representation of a JSON. That is because Jquery handles the stringification I think.

Comment: Yes, jQuery accepts objects and arrays, and stringifies it for you, but should also accept strings, but there's no need to stringify objects, just send them directly when using jQuery